# Generate Makefile that builds the same executable with different flags depending on build target

Tags: cmake

How do I write a CMakeLists.txt file so that CMake generates a Makefile with functionality equivalent to

```
all: proj

debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g -Og
debug: proj

proj: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) main.cpp -o proj
```

In other words, I want to be able to build the same executable in the same folder with `make [build_target]`, but depending on the build target, with different flags.

Currently I have

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

set(PROJ_NAME "proj")

project(${PROJ_NAME} CXX)
add_executable(${PROJ_NAME} main.cpp)

add_custom_target(debug)
target_compile_definitions(debug PUBLIC -DDEBUG -g -Og)
```

But when I'm calling CMake, I get an error saying `target_compile_definitions called with non-compilable target type`, and I don't know how to make it "compilable".

Comment: 1. It's not just debug that I want to add. I also want to add targets where specific features are disabled depending on the target.
2. I want to add more than the default -g -Og flags.
3. I can't actually do `make debug` after running cmake with the above code, so if it's supposed to set up debug and release, it's certainly not doing it.

Also what do you mean by Makefile being not valid? Because it works without errors. I just want cmake to generate one that does the same thing.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: I'm confused. It sounds like you want [a multi-config generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html)? or to just generate multiple makefile buildsystems?

Comment: Somebody asked me for that clarification, hence the comment, but it seems they deleted theirs.

Comment: I just want `make proj` and `make debug` to build the same output with different inputs, without having to run cmake again. I don't know what it is that has to happen in the background to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how CMake is designed to be used. A target in a generated buildsystem is designed to have a stable set of compile options (flags). If you want to change the flags, the buildsystem needs to be regenerated. That's usually a good thing for performance reasons. I'd suggest that you just generate two buildsystems- one for debug, and one for whatever else (I assume release?). That's the idiomatic thing to do in CMake when working with single-config buildsystems (as opposed to [multi-config generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/GENERATOR_IS_MULTI_CONFIG.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd do this by changing the configuration to build the other target or setting up a build directory per configuration, that is if you're not using a multi-config generator anyways. For configuration dependent options you'd use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#configuration-expressions), e.g.

```
target_compile_definitions(proj PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:DEBUG>)
```

If you want to build the same sources with different build system targets, you need to create different cmake targets.

```
set(SOURCES main.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJ_NAME} ${SOURCES})

add_executable(${PROJ_NAME}_debug ${SOURCES})
target_compile_definitions(${PROJ_NAME}_debug PRIVATE DEBUG)
target_compile_options(${PROJ_NAME}_debug PUBLIC PRIVATE -g -Og)
```

You may need to change the output name, but using the same output file path for both targets would be problematic, so be sure to at also put them into seperate dirs

```
set_target_properties(${PROJ_NAME}_debug PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME ${PROJ_NAME}

    #set use different output dir to avoid name conflict with other exe output
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/debug_bin
)
```

Comment: So what I'm getting from this is, what I'm asking for is basically impossible? I have to have either a different output file, or put the output in a different folder instead of overwriting it when I build a different configuration?

Comment: @DmitriRanfft Think about the makefile that would need to be produced and if that makefile would still do what you expect it to do: You'd need to have 2 different rules for building the same file in different ways and once you've built it one way the file would be considered up to date until you change one of the dependencies. Even if you add a target for forcing the build, this would result in the rule created for the `add_executable` up to date. You may of course work with a suffix for the target or similar...